# Problemas com vetores e structs

Tags: c++, struct

Sou meio novato em C++ (até porque o código é básico) e estou tendo certo problema com um exercício que é necessário guardar os dados de 10 pessoas (nome, data de nascimento e altura) utilizando structs.

As structs são:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char nome[50];
    float altura;
} pserhumano;

typedef struct 
{
    float dia;
    float mes;
    float ano;
 } dnasc;
```

E as duas funções são:

```
 void CriaData(dnasc *D[], int i)
 {
     D[i]->mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
     D[i]->ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
     D[i]->dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
 }

 void InserirNome(pserhumano *Z[])
 {
     dnasc a[10];
     for (int contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++) {
       cout << "Insira o seu nome." << endl;
       gets (Z[contador]->nome);
       cout << "Insira a sua idade." << endl;
       cin >> Z[contador]->altura;
       CriaData(&a, contador);
      } 
 }
```

Ao compilar, o output é esse:

```
athos@ubuntu:~$ g++ exercicio1.cpp -w -o a
exercicio1.cpp: In function ‘void InserirNome(pserhumano**)’:
exercicio1.cpp:35:33: error: cannot convert ‘dnasc (*)[10]’ to ‘dnasc**’ for  argument ‘1’ to ‘void CriaData(dnasc**, int)’
        CriaData(&a, contador);
                             ^
exercicio1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
exercicio1.cpp:43:19: error: cannot convert ‘pserhumano (*)[10]’ to ‘pserhumano**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void InserirNome(pserhumano**)’
 InserirNome(&b);
               ^
```

Basicamente, estou tendo problemas em lidar com um vetor de struct e na hora de passar isso pra função. O que poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo uma possível solução para seu problema.

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[50];
    float altura;
} pserhumano;

typedef struct
{
    float dia;
    float mes;
    float ano;
 } dnasc;

 void CriaData(dnasc *D)
 {
     D->mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
     D->ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
     D->dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
 }

 void InserirNome(pserhumano *Z[])
 {
     dnasc a[10];
     for (int contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++) {
       cout << "Insira o seu nome." << endl;
       gets (Z[contador]->nome);
       cout << "Insira a sua idade." << endl;
       cin >> Z[contador]->altura;
       CriaData(&a[contador]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma breve explicação sobre o que estava ocorrendo, melhorando a resposta do @ricardokiki.

A variável `a` é um vetor e ao passar `&a` como argumento da função você estava passando um ponteiro de ponteiro, como a função espera apenas um ponteiro.

Portanto, temos o erro:

> `"cannot convert ‘dnasc (*)[10]’ to ‘dnasc**’..."`